# How can I modify a post depending on the source of the traffic?

Tags: google, ads, customization

I have a wordpress site. If I include some javascript on a post, I show ads on the post. I want to only show that javascript when people come to my site from google search (as opposed to from twitter or facebook -- or by going to the URL directly).

Is there any way to do that from within wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Not a wordpress questions really. You will get much better responses at stackoverflow.com. However you instigated my curiosity... you can get the referral url by using the following javascript:

```
document.referrer
```

You could add that to your current AD script to check if the document.referrer == "some url" before displaying the ad.

See more examples [here](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm)